# Cannot callback NSError in block in release mode framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have build a framework called myTool.framework only in **Release Mode**.

In this framework there is a function with a block callback:

```objectivec
// myTools.h
- (void)initServiceWithKey:(NSString * _Nullable)accessKey
                  complete:(void(^)(NSError *error,  NSInteger roomType))complete;


// myTools.m
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^complete)(NSError * error, NSInteger roomType);
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSError *error;

- (void)initServiceWithKey:(NSString * _Nullable)accessKey
                  complete:(void(^)(NSError *error,  NSInteger roomType))complete {


    balabala...

    if (somethingWrong) {
      self.error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Error Domain" code:-1 userInfo:nil];

      if (self.complete) {
          self.complete(self.error, -1);
          return;
      }
    }
}
```

Then I use it in a demo like this:

```objectivec
[myToos sharedInstance] initServiceWithKey:@"123key" complete:^(NSError * _Nonnull error, NSInteger roomType) {
    if (!error) {

      #error always is nil here when run demo in release mode, roomType is fine.

    }
}
```

When running demo in Debug I can get error normally, but error is always nil in Release as NSInteger is fine.

I already save the error and block as a singleton's property, It didn't work.

Why this and How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: What about `self.complete([NSError errorWithDomain:@"Error Domain" code:-1 userInfo:nil], -1);`?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Cannot capture error either

Comment: What value do you see for `error.code`?

Comment: @RomanPodymov There isn't error at all, so neither is error.code.

Comment: Don't check `if (!error)`, just `if (error.code == -1)`.

Comment: @RomanPodymov The `error` is nil, will the `error.code == -1` is always false?